# WordPress Advanced Custom Field gallery doesn't return an array

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

I have `ACF Plugin` installed and I have a gallery filed in my post. I've tried all [these](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) docs but still getting the error :

```
Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`
```

this happens because the input of the for each is not an array!

Do you have any clue what's wrong with this?
Do you think if I have to set something while I've defined the custom field?

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('mygall');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

    if( $images ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image['ID'], $size ); ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do `error_log(print_r($images, true));` to check what you have in the `$images` variable. Most probably it is empty so you need to look somewhere else why you got not data.

Comment: @ale it's not empty when I echo $images it shows all the images in it's order and style !

Comment: @ale but I want to customize it . see this output :https://image.ibb.co/eiyLPz/Screenshot_2018_09_21_GM_A4704_1.png

Comment: can you please paste the outcome of the error_log of `$images`?

Comment: @ale unfortunately it shows nothing I've tried it .

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180560/discussion-between-afsane-f-and-ale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the fact that you are using `get_field()` instead `get_fields()`. That's way you don't get an array.

If it still doesn't work check the documentation for `get_fields()` [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/). Try to debug it like using only `get_fields()` and see what is the output. If it is an empty array then it means that you are calling the function out of the `loop` and it can't get the post id. So do a second test with manually setting the post id like `get_fields(123);` and check the results. If there are no results then there is something wrong with that post. And if there are results then you can do a final test with checking what will be the result of `get_fields(123, 'gallery')`.

All the above debugging can be wrapped in something like:

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r( get_fields(123) );
echo '</pre>';
```

Basically this will give you some idea of what is the structure of the data that you get from this function and how you can manipulate it so to get what you need.

Comment: With this the images in echo are not even shown any more .

Comment: I've updated the answer with some debugging tips. Hope it will give you some direction.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out and share you the result .

Comment: I check it out and find out the post I was trying to set a gallery for had the malformed images and as a result the $images was empty or some thing which was not an array! Thank you